# Get all the files from a FTP location with previous week's dates in the file names using Linux

Tags: linux, shell, date, ftp, get

I have a weird requirement where I have to get the files from a FTP(Lets say FTP1) location and place it on my current FTP(Lets say FTP2) location. The issue is, these are daily files (in a pattern Sales_YYYYMMDD_report.csv) and are placed every day on FTP1 and my process usually runs on Monday(eg. 09-Sept-2013) which has to use the file of the previous week starting from Sunday(eg. 01-Sept-2013) to Saturday(eg. 07-Sept-2013) place them on FTP2 location and then run the Informatica process. For an instance, if I run the process on Monday,09-Sept-2013, I have to pull all the files from FTP1 which have file names such as

```
Sunday file --> Sales_20130901_report.csv  
Monday file --> Sales_20130902_report.csv  
Tuesday file --> Sales_20130903_report.csv  
Wednesday file --> Sales_20130904_report.csv  
Thursday file --> Sales_20130905_report.csv  
Friday file --> Sales_20130906_report.csv  
Saturday file --> Sales_20130907_report.csv
```

How can I achieve this in a shell script? I know the part to get the files from another FTP, but I am not sure how to get the 7 files.

P.S: I cannot use the file creation/last modified timestamps to get the files. Irrespective of the created timestamp and the day I run my Informatica process, I have to get the files which have last week's dates in the file names and put in my FTP2 location and then continue with them.

Please help...

Comment: Do you know the exact name of the file - and are you sure they exist? Is it acceptable to use a bash script to do this?

Comment: ya, we can use Bash script for this too. Above sample file names are pretty much the same names of the files I have to work with. eg. Sales_20130901_report.csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script should have all the elements you need:

```
#!/bin/bash
# assuming this is run from the directory where you want the files
# to end up

function getIt {
  echo "ftp-ing " $1
  # here comes the heart of the ftp session
  ftp -inv << _EOF_
  open home.machine.com
  user myname mypassword
  cd /the/path/where/the/file/lives
  get $1
  bye
_EOF_
  }

# generate the seven file names for the previous seven days:
for d in {1..7}
  do
    theCmd="/bin/date -v -"$d"d +%Y%m%d"
    theDate=`$theCmd`
    fileName="Sales_"$theDate"_report.csv"
    getIt $fileName
  done
```

It should be mostly self-explanatory: but note in particular that the end of the `heredoc` (the "encapsulated ftp script", if you like) MUST be at the start of the line, with no white space before it, and no white space after. Also - depending on how important security on this machine is you may want to do something different with the password; maybe you even want to use something other than "vanilla" ftp. But I think this should get you going in the right direction.

Tested up to the actual `ftp` bit itself... when I comment that out the script correctly calls `getIt()` seven times, with a string representing the filename you specified. Obviously I can't easily test the ftp...

Note also this will just copy to the directory where you start the script from; if you need it to end up somewhere else you may need a second `ftp` script. I'm sure you can figure that out though.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following command in linux (tested on Cent OS 6), change the -1 day for appropriate dates

yesterday="`date +%Y%m%d --date="-1 day"`"

more reference = http://blog.midnightmonk.com/85/bash/bash-date-manipulation.shtml

Comment: Mehul, I get the previous dates, that is not the problem. I have to get all the files from the FTP1 which have the previous week's dates in them. Is there a simpler way to loop in and get the files. Thanks...